# Spring JDBC Template can't execute Queries containing nested Query in the FROM clause

Tags: mysql, spring, jdbc, database-connection, spring-jdbc

Spring JDBC Template can't execute Queries containing nested Query in the FROM clause

I am using spring JDBCTemplate to execute queries. And the code uses SqlRowSet, instead of RowMapper or RowExtractor.

Now there seems to be some problem while executing a Query which contains a nested query in the FROM clause. When I test the query in the Workbench or Mysql Console, it works perfectly fine.

**Following is the code**

```
JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(txManager.getDataSource());
try {
    String sqlQuery = "SELECT profile.user_profile_id, profile.user_id, profile.first_name "
                    + "FROM (SELECT user_profile_id, user_id, first_name FROM user_profile WHERE user_id = 1) AS profile";

    // The following line is throwing exception
    SqlRowSet resultSet = jdbcTemplate.queryForRowSet(sqlQuery); 

    if (resultSet.next()) {
          ...... // Put in a POJO 
    }  
} catch(DataAccessException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
     // Throw Proper User Defined Exception
}
```

But, if I change the Query to the following, it works perfectly fine.

```
String sqlQuery = "SELECT profile.user_profile_id, profile.user_id, profile.first_name "
                 + "FROM user_profile AS profile";
```

**NOTE :** My database name is *titans*

I am getting the following exception. It says that table 'titans.*' doesn't exists. It seems absurd to me.

```
org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: StatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [SELECT prof.user_profile_id, prof.user_id, prof.first_name, prof.last_name FROM (SELECT inner_prof.user_profile_id, inner_prof.user_id, inner_prof.first_name, inner_prof.last_name FROM titans.user_profile AS inner_prof WHERE user_id = 1) AS prof ]; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'titans.*' doesn't exist
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:237)
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:72)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:407)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:456)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.queryForRowSet(JdbcTemplate.java:501)
at com.titansinc.user.dsp.impl.UserDSP.getUserProfileByUserID(UserDSP.java:188)
at com.titansinc.user.service.UserService.getUserProfileByUserID(UserService.java:36)
at controllers.com.titans.play.controllers.Application.testReadMethod(Application.java:40)
at Routes$$anonfun$routes$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$6$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(routes_routing.scala:141)
at Routes$$anonfun$routes$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$6$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(routes_routing.scala:141)
at play.core.Router$HandlerInvokerFactory$$anon$4.resultCall(Router.scala:264)
at play.core.Router$HandlerInvokerFactory$JavaActionInvokerFactory$$anon$15$$anon$1.invocation(Router.scala:255)
at play.core.j.JavaAction$$anon$1.call(JavaAction.scala:55)
at play.GlobalSettings$1.call(GlobalSettings.java:67)
at play.core.j.JavaAction$$anonfun$11.apply(JavaAction.scala:82)
at play.core.j.JavaAction$$anonfun$11.apply(JavaAction.scala:82)
at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24)
at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24)
at play.core.j.HttpExecutionContext$$anon$2.run(HttpExecutionContext.scala:40)
at play.api.libs.iteratee.Execution$trampoline$.execute(Execution.scala:46)
at play.core.j.HttpExecutionContext.execute(HttpExecutionContext.scala:32)
at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$.apply(Future.scala:31)
at scala.concurrent.Future$.apply(Future.scala:492)
at play.core.j.JavaAction$class.apply(JavaAction.scala:82)
at play.core.Router$HandlerInvokerFactory$JavaActionInvokerFactory$$anon$15$$anon$1.apply(Router.scala:252)
at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$4$$anonfun$apply$5.apply(Action.scala:130)
at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$4$$anonfun$apply$5.apply(Action.scala:130)
at play.utils.Threads$.withContextClassLoader(Threads.scala:21)
at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(Action.scala:129)
at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(Action.scala:128)
at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145)
at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Action.scala:128)
at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Action.scala:121)
at play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$mapM$1.apply(Iteratee.scala:483)
at play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$mapM$1.apply(Iteratee.scala:483)
at play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$flatMapM$1.apply(Iteratee.scala:519)
at play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$flatMapM$1.apply(Iteratee.scala:519)
at play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$flatMap$1$$anonfun$apply$14.apply(Iteratee.scala:496)
at play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$flatMap$1$$anonfun$apply$14.apply(Iteratee.scala:496)
at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24)
at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24)
at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:41)
at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:393)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
   Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'titans.*' doesn't exist
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:377)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:360)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:978)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3887)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3823)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2435)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2582)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2526)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2484)
at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeQuery(StatementImpl.java:1446)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Field.getCollation(Field.java:448)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetMetaData.isCaseSensitive(ResultSetMetaData.java:549)
at com.sun.rowset.CachedRowSetImpl.initMetaData(CachedRowSetImpl.java:722)
at com.sun.rowset.CachedRowSetImpl.populate(CachedRowSetImpl.java:639)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.SqlRowSetResultSetExtractor.createSqlRowSet(SqlRowSetResultSetExtractor.java:79)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.SqlRowSetResultSetExtractor.extractData(SqlRowSetResultSetExtractor.java:62)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.SqlRowSetResultSetExtractor.extractData(SqlRowSetResultSetExtractor.java:45)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$1QueryStatementCallback.doInStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:446)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:396)
... 44 more
```

Comment: do you test in a sql console your entire query before?

Comment: yeah @johnnynemonic, it's working fine in mysql console and workbench. The problem seems to be with JDBCTemplate.

Comment: `MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'titans.*' doesn't exist`   Check for jdbc datasource configuration. Is it configured to "titans" database?

Comment: @Arunkumar jdbc datasource is configured properly. All other queries are working fine. Only this one is causing the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like `queryForRowSet(sqlQuery)` method has this bug. I reported the bug on spring JIRA.

An alternative approach would be to use `ResultSetExtractor or RowMapper` to implement the db call. This implementation doesn't throw any exceptions for the above mentioned queries.

```
....

String sqlQuery = ".....";
Object[] parameters = { .... };

ITestPOJO resultList = jdbcTemplate.query(sqlQuery, parameters, 
     new ResultSetExtractor<ITestPOJO>() {

        @Override
        public ITestPOJO extractData(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException, DataAccessException {
             // TODO use ResultSet from here 
             // return ITestPOJO object
        }
    });         
...
```